# React SetState not setting state

Tags: reactjs

I have a component state like this:

```
this.state = {
  mode: 'in',
  current: {
    messageId: '',
  },
};
```

then I setState like this:

```
const newState = update(this.state, { mode: { $set: 'out' },
                                      current: { messageId: { $set: '123' } } });
this.setState(newState);
```

I've been doing it this way since I started learning React and it worked except this time it's not working for whatever reason..

With `console.log(newState)` it shows that they are both correctly being updated: `mode: 'out'` and `'current.messageId': '123'`.

However when I `setState` only `'current.messageId': '123'` is being set but `mode` still equals `in`.

`mode` state changes the layout of the page from `<InLayout />` to `<OutLayout />`. I've used it this way many times before and it worked and still works...

So confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the `update` method do?

Comment: I don't know what your `update` method does, but try this `this.setState({...newState})`

Comment: Not sure what update function does. But this is what you should do     `const newState = {...this.state};
newState.mode = 'out';
newState.current.messageId = '123';
this.setState(newState);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get mutated state right after using setState. Please check the following.

[image]